# Embedded images don't work with Modules

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have an Image component with a source set to an embedded image. When I load
this module into a shell module, the image doesn't show up. Why?

I have to put an instance of that image into the shell module's codebase just to
make it work. That shouldn't be, right?

Any ideas?

Thank you for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Flash/Flex Builder to create the initial module make sure to check out the project properties (right click the project in the navigator and go to properties) and make sure the folder/file in question appears as included in the assets... well that is if you compile it as a swc... sorry possibly that's going off track.  Make sure when you build the module you aren't optimizing it for a particular application that will cause it to not include resources that the application you're optimizing for also contains (project->properties->flex modules->edit->do not optimize).

Comment: Perhaps that is problem right there. Under 'Flex Modules' I don't have anything listed. Do I have to create a module to build for the project?

Comment: a bit confused... to clarify the end goal here is to create a module then use said module in another application correct?  If this is the case lets say ProjectA which is where you're building the module should have a component in it that is a Flex Module (created by right clicking the folder and hitting new->flex module).  Now in ProjectA you will see in the properties a module section and you want it to not optimize (also an option when you first create the module).  Then in Project B you should be including the swf from ProjectA (ModuleLoader) will comment again with another possibility

Comment: otherwise you're creating a library project which will generate a swc file then using that as the dependency of ProjectB, in this case you want to check the assets included in the project properties for the swc (ProjectA), let me know which one sounds more like what you're doing and I can probably point you in the right direction

Comment: Got it. I've updated the output folder of the module to be the folder in the main app. I've added the 'src' file of the module to the build path of the main app and added it as a module of the main app, too. I believe that's all I need to do. It's not working right now but I think I have some tweaks to do before I fully understand this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: FOLLOW UP: It's still not working. From what I understand, the shell application must have a module defined under 'Flex Modules' for each module it loads: Fine, I do that. It points to the default mxml file of the app. In addition, I add the 'src' directory of the loaded module to the build path of the shell application (under properties). Then, in the loaded module, I point the output path to the appropriate place in the shell application's directory. After all this, I still don't see the images. Am I doing this wrong? Thank you for your help.